# Is there a way to ignore a site, beta or live?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, notifications, global-inbox, deleted-accounts

My time on the SE sites is very limited these days. When I am here, 99 times out of 100, I need to spend it doing moderation duties and meta discussions. I wish it were different because I really enjoy these sites, but reality dictates otherwise.

I am, however, subscribed to a number of sites in the SE family, which were done on a whim. But given my short time spurts here, I really prefer to focus my time on those few sites that are of practical interest to me, and ignore the rest. The odd comment winds up in my Inbox and it is just noise, really, and I wish there was a way to turn them off. I do this with other accounts, mailing lists, and whatnot that clutters up my mailboxes after a while, so it would be nice to close the spigot here every once in a while, too.

Is there a way for me to ignore a site, or simply close my account on a particular site so I no longer receive notifications of any kind? [I saw this question elsewhere here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account), but that seems like a global solution, and instead I want to do something like that by site.

Comment: I second this.  There should be something less drastic than account deletion to surpress inbox notifications from a particularly noisy site (while, say, you're on vacation and have more-important notifications to pay attention to).

Answer (score 2):

As far as the inbox goes, if you don't reply to things, or create new content, the amount of things you receive in your inbox will go down with time.

If you really do want to delete your membership on a particular site, you can follow the instructions as listed in the question you linked, but make sure they only do it for particular sites.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the requirement of moderators to delete accounts, thus the question. It seems to me that the ability to ignore a site or simply close an account is one that I should be able to do just as freely as I was to create it. Why make this a moderator task? It doesn't make any sense on the surface.

Comment: @PhilipRegan: I *guess* the main reason it's a moderator task is that it's simply a very rare requirement.

Comment: @PhilipRegan: I'm pretty sure the profile deletion system has changed in the last several years, but in any case, you can currently delete your user profile on a site-by-site basis – it doesn't automatically apply to your network account as a whole – and it doesn't require moderator involvement (though high-rep users may have to wait for a CM to handle the request).